# difference between print and return in python

Tags: python

When I run this following code:

```
def foo():
  for n in range(0, 10):
      return('bar', n)


print(foo())
```

it prints:

```
('bar', 0)
```

When I run the exact same code but replace the 'return' with 'print'

```
def foo():
    for n in range(0, 10):
        print('bar', n)


print(foo())
```

it prints the following:

```
bar 0
bar 1
bar 2
bar 3
bar 4
bar 5
bar 6
bar 7
bar 8
bar 9
None
```

in the code where I use return, shouldn't it give the results same as above because I'm returning every n?

Comment: In the second example you notice the `None` at the end, that is the return value.

Comment: You are not returning every `n`. You can only return once.

Comment: "shouldn't it give the results same as above because I'm returning every n?" No, once you `return`, the function *terminates* and *returns control to the caller*

Answer (score 0):

Because when it reaches the first return, the function ends.

For this reason, inside the loop and in the first iteration, it run the Return command and the function ends.